# Copying urdu text from db columns while exporting csv using bcp utility

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exporting data from tables using BCP utility. Some columns in db contains urdu language text. 
When the file is exported I only see ??? in place of urdu text. 
I am not able to figure out what's wrong ? what am I missing ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-w` switch to allow bcp copy unicode data.

Something like......

```
bcp MyDB.dbo.TableName OUT D:\Folder\TestFile.txt -T -w
```